# C++ code with Runtime error

Tags: c++, debugging, runtime, runtime-error

I can't figure out what is the problem when I run the code on ideone it gives me Runtime error , It's a UVa problem (UVa 11321).

I have N numbers and a positive integer M. I have to sort the N numbers
in ascending order of their modulo M value.

1. If there is a tie between an odd number and an even number (that
   their modulo M value is the same) then the odd number will precede the
   even number.
2. If there is a tie between two odd numbers (that is their modulo M
   value is the same) then the larger odd number will precede the smaller
   odd number and.
3. If there is a tie between two even numbers (that their modulo M value
   is the same) then the smaller even number will precede the larger even
   number.
4. For remainder value of negative numbers follow the rule of C
   programming language: A negative number can never have modulus
   greater than zero. E.g. -100 MOD 3 = -1, -100 MOD 4 = 0

Any help please !!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

bool sortPair (const pair < int , int > &x , const pair < int , int > &y)
    {

    if ( x.second > 0 && y.second < 0 )
    {
    return x.second < y.second ;
    }

    if ( x.second < 0 && y.second > 0 )
    {
        return y.second < x.second ;
    }

    if ( (x.second % 2 != 0) && (y.second % 2 == 0) && (x.first == y.first))
    {
        return x.second > y.second ;
    }

   if ( (x.second % 2 == 0) && (y.second % 2 != 0) && (x.first == y.first) )
    {
        return y.second > x.second ;
    }



   if ( (x.second % 2 == 0) && (y.second % 2 == 0) && (x.first == y.first) )
    {
        if ( x.second < y.second )
        {
        return y.second > x.second ;
        }
        else
        {
            return x.second < y.second ;
        }
    }

   if ( (x.second % 2 != 0) && (y.second % 2 != 0) && (x.first == y.first) )
    {
        if( x.second < y.second )
        {
            return x.second < y.second ;
        }
        else
        {
            return x.second > y.second ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }




    }



    int main()
    {


    while ( true )
    {

        int n , m , x ,idx ;
        cin >> n >> m ;
        idx = n + 1 ;

        vector < pair < int , int > > u ;

        while ( cin >> x && idx != 0 )
        {
            u.push_back( make_pair ( x % m , x ) ) ;
            idx-- ;

         }


        sort ( u.begin() , u.end() - 1 ) ;
        sort ( u.begin() , u.end() - 1 , sortPair ) ;


        cout << n << " " << m << endl ;

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i )
        {
            cout << u.at(i).second << "\n" ;
        }

        cout << "0 0" << endl ;

    }

    return 0;
    }
```

[ideone link](http://ideone.com/InnFZX)
[Problem link](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=2296)

Comment: @kuroineko thank you I will try to rewrite it , but can you help me with runtime error right now ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recommendation: fire up the debugger and start a-steppin'. That and think on what `while (true)` means.

Comment: My advice: forget about std: and C++ and debuggers. Instead, think about your algorithm, with a pen and a bit of paper. Making a program compile or run without errors does not mean it will be a good program, nor does it guarantee it will produce the expected result.

Comment: I know it is an infinite loop but the judge accepts it, whatever even i make a limitation condition for the code it still gives me runtime error @user4581301

Comment: Hint: "in ascending order of their modulo M value" != `false`.

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful to break down your code into smaller, clearly understandable, pieces.

Here's my attempt at re-writing your function, with commentary that made sense to me.

**PS** This is untested code.

```
bool sortPair (const pair < int , int > &x,
               const pair < int , int > &y)
{
   int xmod = x.first;
   int xval = x.second;

   int ymod = y.first;
   int yval = y.second;

   // The simple case. The mods are not equal.
   if ( xmod != ymod )
   {
      return xmod < ymod;
   }

   // Add the complicated logic when xmod is equal to ymod.

   bool x_is_odd = ((xval%2) != 0);
   bool y_is_odd = ((yval%2) != 0);
   bool x_is_even = !x_is_odd;
   bool y_is_even = !y_is_odd;

   // Check whether one is odd and the other is even.
   // If there is a tie between an odd number and an even number (that
   // their modulo M value is the same) then the odd number will precede
   // the even number.
   if ( x_is_odd && y_is_even )
   {
      return true;
   }
   if ( y_is_odd && x_is_even )
   {
      return false;
   }

   // Check whether both are odd.
   // If there is a tie between two odd numbers (that is their modulo M value
   // is the same) then the larger odd number will precede the smaller odd
   // number and.
   if ( x_is_odd && y_is_odd )
   {
      return (yval < xval);
   }

   // If we come here, then both are even.
   // If there is a tie between two even numbers (that their modulo M value
   // is the same) then the smaller even number will precede the larger
   // even number.
   assert ( x_is_even && y_is_even );
   return (xval < yval);
}
```

Also, modify the code that creates the elements of the vector so that the mods of negative values are taken care of before the call to sort them.

```
     int mod = x%m;
     if ( x < 0 )
     {
        mod -= m;
     }

     u.push_back( make_pair ( mod, x ) ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks alot your code learned me a lot and it made the code more simple , I tested the code but also after your edit it still gives runtime error @r-sahu